# My controller is erroring with a 404 page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting 404 on when I try to across my page via www.mywebsite.com/hello create a controller. I will detail what I have. Please can anyone see anything obviously wrong?

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.well-known) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.well-known) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Hello extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
}

public function index(){
    $this->load->view('hello');
}

}
```

view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

routes

```
$route['hello'] = 'hello';
```

config

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: what if you ignore the .htacess , do you still have the same error ?

Comment: are you trying to remove index.php from url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **.htaccess file should be like this **

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

and **config/config.php** file should be like this

```
$config['base_url'] = $base_url;

$config['index_page'] = ''; //keep it empty.

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';


$config['url_suffix'] = '';

$config['language'] = 'english';

$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';


$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
```

then again try. I hope it will be fixed.